# S3 Server access logging vs CloudTrail logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given that both services are enabled (A single S3 bucket with Server Access Logging enabled and CloudTrail with object-level logging enabled for that bucket):
1. What events will initiate logging from both services?
2. In such a case, what data will one service contain that the other will not?
3. What events will result in a log created by only one of the services?

I am having a hard time understanding the logical difference between those two, as both support object level logging.

Answer (score 2):

This is summed up in the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/logging-with-S3.html). Note that AWS recommends CloudTrail.